# jersey fails to parse string to enum with jackson

Tags: java, json, curl, jersey, jackson

I have this server code:

```
@Path("/saveE2eResult")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
public void saveE2eResult(E2eResults e2eResult) {

    System.out.println("saved "+e2eResult.toString());
}
```

and

```
public enum E2eResults {

    SUCCESS("Success"),
    FAIL("Fail");

    private final String name;

    private E2eResults(String s) {
    name = s;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static E2eResults getEnumFromValue(String value) {
    for (E2eResults e2eResult : values()) {
        if (e2eResult.equalsName(value)) {
            return e2eResult;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    public boolean equalsName(String otherName) {
    // (otherName == null) check is not needed because name.equals(null) returns false
    return name.equals(otherName);
    }

    public String toString() {
    return this.name;
    }

}
```

i try to call curl and get:

```
I curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"e2eResult":"SUCCESS"}' http://localhost:8083/sdk/saveE2eResult
```

> Can not construct instance of com.w.sdkService.operations.uiDto.E2eResults, problem: null
>        at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@1a81d811; line: 1, column: 1]%

how can i fix this?